# Can't create Virtual Device (AVD) in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin

I downloaded everything from the Android SDK (literally everything), and the version is 24.xx.
I want to make a Nexus 5 (4,97") AVD, but it requires API Level 19.
And when I try to install Xamarin again, it says that I haven't installed Xamarin v3.9.236. When I try to install, it gives me 3 errors:

```
**Installation of 'Xamarin' failed with more than one exception (attempt 3)**
```

Errors while installing items.
Exception type: System.AggregateException
Installation of archive 'C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\Xamarin.VisualStudio_3.9.236.msi' failed with exception.

Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Full stack trace:
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem download)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()

Installation of archive 
'C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\Xamarin.VisualStudio_3.9.236.msi' failed with exception.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Full stack trace:
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem download)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()

Installation of archive 'C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\Xamarin.VisualStudio_3.9.236.msi' failed with exception.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Full stack trace:
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem download)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()

Comment: try installing as admin?

Comment: Okay so actually i was installing every package outside Xamarin studio, because i started the Android SDK outside Xamarin... I just checked that in Xamarin there is another Android SDK and nothing was installed, so that was the problem

Comment: If you've found the answer I would recommend posting it as an answer or deleting the question if you think it's not useful enough.